# Cross-Platform Default Save Path

Tags: python

I'd like to code a cross-platform default save path for my runtime data. For Windows, I suspect that the user folder would be a good place. Is there any good cross platform, accepted path?

My current solution for Windows is: `os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'myapp')`

Comment: What's wrong with `os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'myapp')`?

Comment: Your current solution is fine if you need/want to persistent the data. You could also have a look to the `tempfile` module and use temporary locations like `tempfile.gettempdir()`.